# MovieClip not reacting how I intended on rollover

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-listener

I thought I had it but I am still not able to get my movieClip to play(). I am getting the trace that its making it into the "updateBomb" function on rollover but my currentBomb is not going to frame 2 and playing. Any ideas why this is happening? Could it be because my movieclips are in a container MC?

```
     function getStarted(event:MouseEvent){
         startClip.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, getStarted);

         for (var i:int = 1; i < 11; i++) {

             var currentBomb:MovieClip = bombClip["bomb_" + i];

             trace(currentBomb);
            currentBomb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function (evt:MouseEvent):void { updateBomb(currentBomb); });
            }

            bombClip.play();


     }

function updateBomb(currentBomb:MovieClip):void {
    trace("in update bomb");
    trace(currentBomb);
    currentBomb.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

I added a trace currentBomb in updateBomb and this is what I get

```
[object bombNum1_5]
in update bomb
[object bombNum1_5]
in update bomb
[object bombNum1_5]
in update bomb
[object bombNum1_5]
in update bomb
[object bombNum1_5]
in update bomb
[object bombNum1_5]
```

When I rollover different bombs. Do I need to reference the bombs by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding an event listener using an anonymous function, creating a closure by storing the currentBomb in the mouse roll over handler.

However, that currentBomb variable is being changed in the loop. And each anonymous function has a reference to it. So when you mouse over each movie clip, they all point to the same bomb (the last one in the loop).

Instead of using the anonymous function, just add an event listener like below. The event handler can rely on the fact that the event came from a `MovieClip` and call it's `gotoAndPlay()` method:

```
// inside the for loop...
currentBomb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, updateBomb);

// roll over event handler
function updateBomb(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var currentBomb:MovieClip = event.target as MovieClip;
    if (currentBomb) // is null if above line fails
        currentBomb.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks I think I was over thinking it.